# IBM MQ/Flume/Cloudera - Cannot /home/user/JNDI-Directory

Tags: ibm-mq, cloudera, flume

I'm trying to connect the IBM MQ Docker Image (Windows) to Flume (Cloudera VM)
My Steps:

1. Start Cloudera VM (ip = 10.0.2.15)
2. Run IBM MQ Docker

`docker run \
          --env LICENSE=accept \
          --env MQ_QMGR_NAME=QM1 \
          --publish 1414:1414 \
          --publish 9443:9443 \
          --detach \
          ibmcom/mq`

and

`docker volume create qm1data`

3. Login to the docker

   `docker exec -it MyDockerName /bin/bash`

   `cd /opt/mqm/java/bin/`

Then run

```
./JMSAdmin -> "DEFINE QCF(confact) QMGR(QM1) tran(client) chan(DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN) host(10.0.2.15) port(1414) DEFINE Q(DEV.QUEUE.1) QUEUE(DEV.QUEUE.1) QMGR(QM1) END" -v
```

Then run `./JMSAdmin`
and I Have the Following error:

```
....
Starting IBM MQ classes for Java(tm) Message Service Administration

JNDI initialization failed, please check your JNDI settings and service.
The name '"/home/user/JNDI-Directory"' cannot be resolved
For additional information on the cause of this problem run with the -v argument
```

Any advice? I'm an IBM MQ newbie.

Comment: There is a config file that JMSAdmin uses you need to specify the path where you want it to create the directory in that config file.

Comment: Thanks, @JoshMc. I saw that file. But I can´t open it. I try nano,vi, vim.

Comment: Which file?  What error do you receive?

Comment: @JoshMc when I do docker exec -it MyDockerName /bin/bash

cd /opt/mqm/java/bin/ i see a jms config file but I can´t edit any file in this folder.

Comment: You usually need to grant yourself write access to JMSAdmin before you can edit it.